# File pointer does not works when moved to a class?

Tags: c++

So I found this solution to call a python script and it works in Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.6.2. I moved the three methods into a separate class and it no longer works.  I thought I could figure it out but have just been beating myself up so I am here asking for help from readers who are much more knowledgeable than myself.  The working code follows.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void close_file(std::FILE* fp) {
    std::fclose(fp);
}

std::string exec_python(const char* scriptCommand) {
    std::array<char, 256> buffer;
    std::string result;
    std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(&close_file)> _pipe(_popen(scriptCommand, "r"), close_file);
    if (!_pipe) {
        throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed!");
    }
    while (fgets(buffer.data(), static_cast<int>(buffer.size()), _pipe.get()) != nullptr) {
        result += buffer.data();
    }  
    return result;
}
std::string call_script(std::string ScriptLoc, std::string Script_Parameters) {
    std::string ScriptInput = ScriptLoc + " " + Script_Parameters;
    std::string result = exec_python(ScriptInput.c_str());
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::string LOne = "python.exe \"C:\\Users\\.....\\source\\repos\\PyApplication1\\PyApplication1.py\"";
    std::string LTwo = " Message";
    //system(LTwo.c_str());
    std::string oRez=call_script(LOne,LTwo);
    std::cout <<"Results:"+oRez << std::endl;
}
```

The separate class that will not compile and related error messages follow. first is the header file, iTool.h.

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

    class iTool {
    public:
        void close_file(std::FILE* fp);
        std::string exec_python(const char* scriptCommand);
        std::string call_script(std::string ScriptLoc, std::string Script_Parameters);
        iTool();
    };
```

The second is the iTool.cpp.

```
#include "iTool.h"

void iTool::close_file(std::FILE* fp) {
    std::fclose(fp);
}

std::string iTool::exec_python(const char* scriptCommand) {
    std::array<char, 256> buffer;
    std::string result;
    std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(&close_file)> _pipe(_popen(scriptCommand, "r"), close_file);
    if (!_pipe) {
        //throw std::runtime_error("_popen() failed!");
    } else { throw std::runtime_error("_popen() failed!"); }
    while (fgets(buffer.data(), static_cast<int>(buffer.size()), _pipe.get()) != nullptr) {
        result += buffer.data();
    }
    return result;
}
std::string iTool::call_script(std::string ScriptLoc, std::string Script_Parameters) {
    std::string ScriptInput = ScriptLoc + " " + Script_Parameters;
    std::string result = exec_python(ScriptInput.c_str());
    return result;
}
iTool::iTool() = default;
```

The error messages.:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2088   '!': illegal for class  TestAppliance1  C:\Users\....\source\repos\TestAppliance1\iTool.cpp 11

Error   C2276   '&': illegal operation on bound member function expression  TestAppliance1  C:\Users\...\source\repos\TestAppliance1\iTool.cpp  10  

Error   C2514   'std::unique_ptr': class template cannot be constructed TestAppliance1  C:\Users\...\source\repos\TestAppliance1\iTool.cpp  10

Error   C2660   'fgets': function does not take 2 arguments TestAppliance1  C:\Users\...\source\repos\TestAppliance1\iTool.cpp  14  

Error   C2662   '_Get_deleter_pointer_type<_Ty,remove_reference<_Ty1>::type,void>::type std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx>::get(void) noexcept const': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'std::unique_ptr' to 'const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx> &' TestAppliance1  C:\Users\...\source\repos\TestAppliance1\iTool.cpp  14
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you getting an error?  If so, please post the full error message

Comment: Hi, to help us help you can you try to make a [minimally reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The code presented is complete and can be copied into source files in a VS C++ project,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tripped over a non-static member function having a hidden `this` parameter and not matching the prototype expected for a deleter function.

Instead of `void (*)(std::File*)`, the proposed deleter looks something like `void (iTool::*(std::File*)`

You can solve the problem by wrapping the function call with a lamda expression that captures `this`, but since `close_file`  doesn't use `this` (something wrong with that--`fp` should probably be a member variable--that is outside the scope of this question), lets go with making it a `static` member function. The asker can clean up the ideological problems later.

In the `iTool` class definition,

```
void close_file(std::FILE* fp);
```

becomes

```
static void close_file(std::FILE* fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

After you create a class you must create an instance of that class in the main function before you can use it:

```
iTool tool()
```

Inside you mean function.....
Also one word of caution for you my friend, if you do not know what:

```
iTool::iTool() = default;
```

Sets your variables to please do not use it...... You can always define those variables by yourself in your private part, if you know what the default does, by all means go ahead.

Comment: You are not addressing the issue which is that moving the working code into class structures will not compile.

Comment: If you do not create a class of the object, how do you expect it to compile???